# How do I modify the urls that are being generated by ember-data's REST adapter?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I can account for pluralisation using:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.configure("plurals", {
  query: "queries"
});
```

but I need to append '.json' to all of the routes that are being generated as the API I am working with throws an error if this does not happen. Struggling to find documentation on ember-data, what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can override the `buildURL` method of your Adapter, example :

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    buildURL: function(record, suffix) {
      return this._super(record,suffix) + '.json'
    }
});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adriencoquio/MtbuR/) for a live example.